# Unable to start Ubuntu 16.04 after installing tomcat

Tags: ubuntu, tomcat

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 version.
Yesterday I installed Tomcat and referred link https://devops.profitbricks.com/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-tomcat-8-on-ubuntu-1604/

After installation, the tomcat was running successfully - because I was able to browse tomcat home page in browser.

However when I restarted Ubuntu, it is unable to start...unable to move after entering login credential of Ubuntu...blank screen is shown.

Comment: installed latest version of tomcat...9.X...Apache tomcat web site.

Comment: Something like [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/348805/starting-tomcat-hangs-on-boot-but-run-successfully-in-command-line)?